# 'int' object is not iterable in python 3

Tags: python, compiler-errors

got a error while compiling the code.

I tried to find smallest and largest value from user's input by storing the input in lists. After 'int' object not iterate problem, couldn't proceed further

```
largest=0
smallest=0
num=[]
while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

    for i in num:
        if i>largest:
            largest=i
    for j in num:
        if j<smallest:
            smallest=j
    if num==12:
        break             
print(largest)
print(smallest)
```

Comment: change variable name for user input, to something else (lets say n). add `num.append(n)` to store user input inside num list.

Comment: You also start with `smallest=0`.  Think about what will happen when you only enter numbers larger than zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment you issue below code line `num` is no longer a list, instead its an `int` type of data.

```
num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
```

As you can understand, there is nothing to iterate over in case of a single integer value.

The right solution is to read your input to a separate variable and append to your list.

```
input_num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
num.append(input_num)
```

Further you will have to change value of your exit clause

```
if num==12:
    break
```

If you desire to stop the loop after 12 inputs, then use `len(num) == 12` in the if condition. In case you want to `break` loop if input number is 12 then change if condition to `if input_num == 12`

Note: Your algorithm has logical errors as well. You are assigning `smallest` to `0` . In case user enters all positive integers as input, your result will incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate through a number which is wrong, you have overwritten your num list to an integer. Instead of the following:

```
num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
```

You should save the number in some other variable and add to num list like:

```
x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
num.append(x)
```

Comment: @CodeManga You cannot do a `num = x` as it will overwrite num(list) to x (integer). You'd want to append x to num, like `num.append(x)` or `num = num + x`